# How to I add something to the .gitignore so that the match is not recursive?

Tags: git, ignore, gitignore

How to I add something to the `.gitignore` so that the match is not recursive?

For example, I wish to ignore the directory `foo` and the file `bar.txt` in the current directory, but not any that exist in subdirectories.

I have tried this for my `.gitignore` file:

```
foo/
bar.txt
```

But unfortunately git applies this recursively, so that `otherdir/bar.txt` and `otherdir/foo/` also get ignored, which is not what I want.

(Is there a command in git that shows me all ignored files, and reference the `.gitignore` file that is responsible for the file being ignored?  This would be useful for debugging.)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The solution is to place a leading slash on the `.gitignore` entries:

```
/foo/
/bar.txt
```

(I thought I tried this before posting on StackOverflow, but clearly I hadn't tried it properly, as this works perfectly.)

Comment: It's possible you tried this, and had some leading/trailing whitespace somewhere which reportedly causes issues with .gitignore. Who knows, either way this question helped me out lol

Answer (score 13):

From the gitignore manpage:

> An optional prefix ! which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. If a negated pattern matches, this will override lower precedence patterns sources.

So `!*` as the first line in your .gitignore will clear all previous patterns.

Comment: Ok, obviously I was doing stuff in a much more complicated fashion all the time :] +1 for the leading slash answer, can't upvote yet.

Comment: +1 so you can upvote now :) Also, I didn't know about the ! prefix.