# Unity project's .gitignore is ignoring meta files

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore

So I'm pretty familiar with git, but have always had a repo master that has created a .gitignore file for me, so this is my first time dealing with it by myself. My problem is that when I commit my Unity project, and pull it from a different computer, the metafiles have been ignored (I suspect), and all of the GameObjects in my scene get deleted. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573405/how-to-prepare-a-unity-project-for-git)  is the tutorial I followed with the gitignore file I am using.

Comment: Are the metafiles in the .gitignore file?  If they are, should they be?

Comment: I don't see anything that strictly says `.meta`. So I'm not sure what I'm ignoring that is including the meta files.

Comment: Is there an entry ignoring the directory where they're generated?

Comment: Keep in mind, that the unity tag if for a different kind of software.

Comment: Did you read the comment about visible metafiles?  You must have visible metafiles, otherwise git will ignore them

Comment: Ok I took the library file out of the gitignore because it had a lot of meta data in it and that seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen lots of people make these huge `.gitignore` files, when really all they need to do is this:

```
# Ignore Everything
/*

# Except for these:
!/.gitignore
!/Assets
!/ProjectSettings
```

What this is doing, is:

1. Ignore everything
2. Then it un-ignores the rest

   1. The `.gitignore` file
   2. The `Assets` folder
   3. The `ProjectSettings` folder

This should the not ignore your meta files, or anything in the `Assets` folder for that matter.

Comment: Are those forward slashes necessary? Or are they good practice?

Comment: I have had issues with it when I leave them out, so that is why I put them there.

Comment: OK, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2476760/5044950) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6574203/5044950) that explain why they're necessary.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub provide a comprehensive .gitignore file for Unity projects that you can choose when setting up your repository.

It is also available [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore) if you are using a different provider.